# SQL Full-Text Search vs. LIKE Search Performance

Tags: sql, performance, search, full-text-search, freetext

I've been searching on the internet and found the Full-Text Search usually have a better performance.

I followed the instructions on [this post](http://thinknook.com/sql-server-english-thesaurus-for-fulltext-search-2012-02-07/) to set up thesaurus tables on my machine so I can play around with it and get more familiar with full-text search.

I am viewing everything in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

When I run the queries. I notice that my `LIKE` search was faster than my `FREETEXT` search, which contradict what I found on most wiki sites/pages.

Below are the query I ran:

```
select *
from TheThesaurus
where freetext(TheDefinition, 'aspire')

select *
from TheThesaurus
where TheDefinition like '%aspire%'
```

The `LIKE` search took 0sec, where the `FREETEXT` search took 6sec.

The `LIKE` search returns 70 rows, where `FREETEXT` search returns 94, which makes `FREETEXT` search more accurate and better result.

Is there something I'm missing that cause the `FREETEXT` search to be mush slower than the LIKE search?

I would really like to use `FREETEXT` search in my program because it returns more hits (collect more data), but the speed was a significant issue.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you look at execution plan?

Comment: Try `UPDATE STATISTICS TheThesaurus`

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a full text index?  If not, see [CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189520%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) at the MSDN site or this link walks you through it using SQL 2008 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29237/SQL-SERVER-2008-Creating-Full-Text-Catalog-and-Ful

Another reason the run times would be different has to do with what the predicates are doing. The LIKE is closer to an exact match. The FREETEXT function "searches for the values that match the meaning of a phrase and not just exact words"  so your FREETEXT command is doing more work. That is from "Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012"